# How Add Strings from Multiple Text Files to Array

Tags: java, android, arrays, for-loop, foreach

I have an string array of text file names. I would like to send this string array through an iterator and have it give me the first X number of characters of each text file. It would then put those strings in to an array that I can include in a list view.

I was planning on using a buffered reader to read the text and then substring it. But as for using the loops to go through each file, I am guessing that you would need to use a for loop or a foreach loop. However I am really unknowledgeable about how to use those.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Edit:

I should have added this earlier. I am using this to show what files have been downloaded and also to give them a preview of the text file. However, like I said above, some of them have not been downloaded. I would like to know which position in the filename array actually exist and to be able to put the retrieved strings in the proper places of the list view. Will this affect any of the current answers? Any ideas?

Comment: An `Array` is not a `List`, please edit your question to be correct/consistent and show us the code you've worked on so far.

Comment: So, you don't know how to use loops?  Or you don't know how to read from a file?  Or something else?  Please be more specific about what you've done so far, and what you do and don't know how to do going forward.  P.S. actual code is *much* better than descriptive text.

Comment: Try using `Scanner` class to read the files to extract the text you need, and then show us where you get stuck (if anywhere)

Comment: I've edited my question. I don't know how to use loops. A simple example of how you would read through the file names and where in the code you would read the text from would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help. This is what I ended up going with:

```
    filenamearray = filenamefinal.split(";");
    try {


        List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < filenamearray.length; i++) {

            File txt = new File(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC) + "/" + filenamearray[i] + ".txt");
            if (txt.exists()) {

                txtread = new FileInputStream(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC) + "/" + filenamearray[i] + ".txt");
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(txtread));
                String text = reader.readLine();
                displaytxt = text.substring(0, 45) + ". . ."
                results.add(displaytxt);
            } else {
                results.add("empty");
            }
        }

        finalversetextarray = new String[results.size()];
        finalversetextarray = results.toArray(finalversetextarray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's name the variables you have:

String array: String filenames[]

x number of chars: int x

array of x chars in file: string chars[]. Assume you set each index to empty string.

```
import java.util.Scanner

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner fin = null;

    // Loop through files
    for(int i = 0; i < filenames.length; i++) {

        // Open the file with a FileReader
        fin = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filenames[i])));

        // Loop through x chars and add to string
        for(int j = 0; j < x && fin.hasNext(); j++) {
            chars[i] += fin.next();
        }

        // Close your file
        fin.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the variable chars a string array? How do I initialize it properly?